# How to get ID of a mentioned user (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def id(ctx, a:str): #a = @user
```

how would I get the ID of a user mentioned in the command, and output it as:

```
await ctx.send(id)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the `User` object:

```
@bot.command(name="id")
async def id_(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.send(user.id)
```

Or to get the `id` of the author:

```
@bot.command(name="id")
async def id_(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.id)
```

Comment: This just changed my life. Use `commands.errors.UserNotFound` to handle a bad `user` argument since you can't do this from inside the function.  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling

Answer (score 2):

Just realized that when you @someone and store it to the variable "a", it contains the user ID in the form of '<@userid>'. So a bit of clean up can get me the user ID

Here's the code:

```
@bot.command()
async def id(ctx, a:str):
    a = a.replace("<","")
    a = a.replace(">","")
    a = a.replace("@","")
    await ctx.send(a)
```

Since my command consists of "rev id @someone", the @someone gets stored in 'a' as the string '<@userid>' instead of '@someone'.

Comment: This may not be reliable due to an inconsistency in how users/nicknames or desktop/mobile apps format the mentions. If you want to format the mention manually, use `a.replace("!", "")` as well. "If the old substring is not found, it returns the copy of the original string."  
https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1912
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle a [mention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) *within* your function, you can get the mention from the context instead of passing the mention as a string argument.

```
@bot.command()
async def id(ctx):
    # Loop through the list of mentioned users and print the id of each.
    print(*(user_mentioned.id for user_mentioned in ctx.message.mentions), sep='\n')
```

`ctx.message.mentions` will return:

> A list of Member that were mentioned. If the message is in a private
> message then the list will be of User instead.

When you loop through `ctx.message.mentions`, each item is a mentioned member with attributes such as id, name, discriminator. Here's another example of looping through the mentioned list to handle each member who was mentioned:

```
for user_mentioned in ctx.message.mentions:
    # Now we can use the .id attribute.
    print(f"{user_mentioned}'s ID is {user_mentioned.id}")
```

It's up to you whether you want to require the argument `a` as shown in the question above. If you do need this, note that the string will sometimes include an [exclamation in the mention](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1912) depending on whether it is:

- for a User *or* command was posted from mobile app: `<@1234567890>`
- for a Nickname *or* command was posted from desktop app: `<@!1234567890>`

Which is why I prefer to get the id from a member/user attribute.