# How do I get the ID of an user in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

We're writing a bot for our Discord Server which is supposed to mention the person that starts a specific command. For this I'd need the ID of the user, but can't figure out how to get it.

```
@bot.command()
async def name():

author = discord.User.id

await bot.say(str(author))
```

We tried it this way, since the documentation says, the ID of a user is in the class User. But the only thing we get is

```
<member 'id' of 'User' objects>
```

In our eyes we got the right param but can't get the ID itself? Do we need to convert it somehow?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026087/how-to-get-id-of-a-mentioned-user-discord-py/53026278#53026278

Comment: If you want to mention a user, you can directly use `user.mention` to get a string that will mention the user when included in a message.

Comment: `discord.User.id` isn't getting the `id` of an instance of the `User` class, it's getting that attribute from the base class itself. You need to instantiate the `User` object correctly, and read values from instances of it. If you haven't instantiated it, how to you expect your code to even know which user you want the ID of?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh In both cases I get only "ctx is a required argument that is missing".

Comment: @RandomDavis I was expecting the ID of the author, as it says. I thought, it would give back the ID of the user that sends the message.

Comment: Looks like you're using the older async branch.

Comment: @KendelVentonda I don't see how you would have thought that would return anything useful. Even if the `name` function provided access to an instance of a `User` (which it does when used correctly), the line `discord.User.id` completely bypasses that, and is instead looking at the definition of the `User` class. It's impossible for that line to return anything else no matter where or when you run it in your project, since it's looking at something completely static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the bot to mention the author of the message in the async branch, you need to refer to that author through the message that invoked the command, `ctx.message`:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def name(ctx):
    await bot.say("{} is your name".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

To get their id:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def myid(ctx):
    await bot.say("{} is your id".format(ctx.message.author.id))
```

Comment: Okay, we had this version as well but as it seems I made a typo. Works fine here and explains a lot. Thanks for the solution and help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a parameter in the function name.  Each bot.command needs to have at least one parameter known as the "context".  Such as:

```
async def name(ctx):
   author = ctx.message.author
   user_name = author.name
```

Comment: Tried this and got "Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: Adjusted this to include the message parameter.  Try this again