# Send a dm in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, dm

I am trying to have it send a dm to a specified user using the on_message event.
So far I've gotten it to get the snowflake id from the mentioned user but can't find a way to send a dm to that user.
I've been looking for hours and haven't found an anwser please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - DM a User Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343245/python-dm-a-user-discord-bot)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of discord.py you are using but assuming you are using a version newer than 1.0:

Use `user.send(message)`.

To be more specific than that I'd need a code snippet or more in depth description of exactly what you are trying to do

To get a user id from a mention:

```
Use a converter to get the User object:

@bot.command(name="id")
async def id_(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.send(user.id)
```

from this post: [How to get ID of a mentioned user (Discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026087/how-to-get-id-of-a-mentioned-user-discord-py)